# Проблема с выводом SearchResult в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory

Пытаюсь вывести имена пользователей из AD в ListBox на WPF

Часть кода вот такая:

```
SearchResultCollection rc = ds.FindAll();

List<SearchResult> resultList = rc.Cast<SearchResult>().ToList();
foreach (SearchResult sr in resultList)
{
UserSearchListBox.ItemsSource = sr.Properties["name"][0].ToString();
}
```

Но вместо того, чтобы выводить в каждую строку имя каждого пользователя, он выводит одного пользователя, и каждую букву кидает в отдельную строку
[image: Скрин ошибки]

Что мне с этим делать, и как мне нормально вывести имена всех пользователей, которые там нашлись? А не только первого, и вот так

Comment: Как вы понимаете это `Properties["name"][0]`? Я дам подсказку: `Properties["name"]` - "Вася", `"Вася"[0]` - `В`.

Comment: Уберите `[0]`..